# Notification not coming to phone:GCM

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) tutorial for GCM notification.I am able register the device but unable to send notifications.
I have also used couple of online services to send notification, they are sending message but with "null" message.
Please help me, what can be wrong
Note: I am in my college network which use proxy to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create some_name.php file with the code below and upload it to server and then open it. It should send the notification.

Don't forget to change: "add_your_server_key_here", "register_id_of_your_device".

```
<?php
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'add_your_server_key_here' );

$registrationIds = array("register_id_of_your_device" );

$msg = array
(
    'message'       => 'your_message',
    'title'         => 'title_of_message',
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'              => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Again same thing is happening.Notification is not coming when running from localhost but it is coming when i run above code through phpfiddle. Also, the message is still 'null'.

Comment: The manual you are mentioned has not updated since October 14, 2012. I think you should follow this documentation:   https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: i think my connection is using proxy, that is why php is unable to connect to  CURLOPT_URL.